# Python fill NaN with previous value

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi I'm having issue on filling `NaN` in the dataframe with previous value, I had imported the csv into the dataframe `stock_store` and create a new df `data[]` and the following code:

```
 # Import csv to df 'stock_store[]'
 stock_store=pd.read_csv('HKEX-01128.csv',parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
 
 data["D-Chg"]=stock_store['Adj Close'] - stock_store['Adj Close'].shift(1, freq='B')
 data["D-Chg"].replace('NaN',np.NaN).fillna('pad')
 print(data["D-Chg"].head(100))

      Date
 2009-10-09         NaN
 2009-10-12   -0.049069
 2009-10-13    0.122673
 2009-10-14    0.110408
 2009-10-15   -0.429356
 2009-10-16    0.159474
 2009-10-19   -0.036801
 2009-10-20    0.061336
 2009-10-21    0.000000
 2009-10-22   -0.208543
 2009-10-23   -0.110407
 2009-10-27         NaN
 2009-10-28   -0.423221
 2009-10-29   -0.012268
```

It doesn't work as the Nan still appearing.
I had tried other method such as `data["D-Chg"].fillna(method='ffill')` or `data[["D-Chg"]==""]=np.NaN` both still doesn't work.

Thanks

JC

Comment: perhaps you need to assign it back? ```data['D-Chg'] = data["D-Chg"].fillna(method='ffill')```

Comment: replace and fillna don't work in-place: you have to assign the result to something (probably the same dataframe column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, just assign the result to the chosen column:

```py
data["D-Chg"] = data["D-Chg"].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Beware that the first element will not get a non-NaN value with this method. You will need to set it manually.